# Chart without libraries

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to build a bar chart without using a library. And my code looks like this

```
export default function App() {
  const fees = [123, 0, 7000, 56, 349, 4500];
  return (
    <div
      className="App"
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "row",
        alignItems: "flex-end"
      }}
    >
      {fees.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={index} style={{ dipley: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
          <p>{item} $</p>
          <div
            style={{
              width: "32px",
              height: `${item * 0.04}px`,
              maxHeight: "195px",
              backgroundColor: "#FC7D5D",
              margin: "0 10px"
            }}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-wildflower-z29s87?file=/src/App.js:23-683)

My problem is that I do not know exactly how to calculate the height of the bars so that they are proportional to the area on which the chart is to be. The chart is placed in a div with a height of **195px** and the highest bar can have this **195px**. And when I have large values, the bars often have the same height despite different values. Like a picture

[image]

I calculate the height of the bars by taking the value from the data (in this case it is the amount) and multiplying by 0.04

Comment: Divide by largest value and then multiply by 195

Comment: There aren't many options when the differences between the max and minimum are large. This is why there are log graphs *(or just divide at a reasonable point and use cool graphics to indicate there's a break in scale)*.